# Maven dependency:analyze reporting seemingly inaccurate results

Tags: maven-3

I am running a mvn dependency:analyze (Maven3.0.2 Java 1.6.0_45) and it is reporting several modules as "unused declared dependencies found"

I would assume that items reported under that heading could be safely removed, and I know I am not using them directly in my project, but when I delete them, things break.

Am I misunderstanding dependency:analyze? Or is it reporting inaccurate results? Or is it really just a best effort report?

Comment: Update at least to Maven 3.0.5...

Comment: I upgraded, but it's still reporting some inaccurate dependencies. One is slf4j, which is kind of suspicious, because nothing in my code calls it directly. But it is still used transitively, but analyze reports that it is unused

Comment: PLease show the full output of your anylyze? Which version of maven-dependency-plugin do you use ? Have you defined it in your pom file?